# Converting rows from one format to another format using linux tools

Tags: regex, linux, sed, grep

let's consider following format of raws:

`| Node[42]{id:42} | Node[208813]{id:208813} | Node[292823]{id:292823} |`

Is is possible to use Linux tools to map it into:
`42,208813,292823`

Where, these numbers are numbers gathered  from `[]`.
Please note that I search for universal method for more columns,  for example:
`| Node[42]{id:42} | Node[208813]{id:208813} | Node[292823]{id:292823} | Node[1]|`  into

`42,208813,292823,1`.
Please note also that `{id:292823}` is optional (it is not mandatory).

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the problem with your approach?

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed 's/[^[]*\[//;s/\][^[]*\[/,/g;s/].*//' file
```

Output:

```
42,208813,292823
```

---

See: `man sed` and [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)